# SQL - Split Data Row and assign score values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologise for the poor title as I didn't have any clue how best to word it.

I have a table whereby I return rows like this:

```
Opener  | Closer  | Policy Ref | Transaction Type
Agent A | Agent B | ABCD01EF01 | New Business
Agent C | Agent C | ZYXA01EF01 | New Business
```

**Create Code**

```
    CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [Opener] varchar(50), [Closer] varchar(50), [PolicyRef] varchar(10), [Transaction Type] varchar(14) )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( 'Agent C', 'Agent C', 'ZYXA01EF01', 'New Business' ), 
( 'Agent A', 'Agent B', 'ABCD01EF01', 'New Business' )

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

We basically score out of 1.0 for the time being, for each row if the Opener = Closer then the 'Score' column should be 1.0 and only return one row, however should the Opener <> Closer than there should be 2 rows with the 'Score' being 0.5 split between the Opener and Closer the output should be like this

```
Agent   | Policy Ref | Transaction Type | Score
Agent A | ABCD01EF01 | New Business     | 0.5 
Agent B | ABCD01EF01 | New Business     | 0.5
Agent C | ZYXA01EF01 | New Business     | 1.0
```

I was thinking a cross apply with row_numbering to define whether there was more than 1 line per "Policy Ref" however I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I have done this previously however it was a stored procedure using temp tables and cte's to update and move the information around, I'm looking for a "low fat" version if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` with `case` expressions:

```
select v.agent, t.policy_ref, t.transaction_type, v.score
from #temptable t cross apply
     (values (opener, (case when t.opener = t.closer then 1.0 else 0.5 end)),
             (case when t.opener <> t.closer then t.closer end, 0.5)
     ) v(agent, score)
where v.agent is not null;
```

Or:

```
select v.agent, t.policy_ref, t.transaction_type,
       (case when t.opener = t.closer then 1.0 else 0.5 end) as score
from #temptable t cross apply
     (values (t.opener, 1),
             (t.closer, 2)
     ) v(agent, which)
where (t.opener <> t.closer) or (which = 1)
```

Comment: Gordon I aspire to be able to write solutions that quick :) Thank you very much sir. I knew I was in the right ballpark with a Cross Apply just wasn't sure how to get the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Just another option is a **UNION ALL**

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Score = 1.0  / sum(1) over(partition by PolicyRef) 
 From  (
        Select Agent = Opener
             ,PolicyRef
             ,[Transaction Type]
         from #temptable
        Union All
        Select Agent = Closer
             ,PolicyRef
             ,[Transaction Type]
         from #temptable
         Where Opener<>Closer
       ) A
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I seems that you are trying to make a too complex table, for data that would be best organized in several tables. This should help you solve your count issue.

It would make sense to me to make more than one table so that you can assign unique keys.
I would create a policy table with a unique key for each policy ref
Then another table for each agent with a unique key per agent.
And then a third table that would be similar to the table you did.

```
Opener  | Closer  | Policy Ref | Transaction Type
Agent A | Agent B | ABCD01EF01 | New Business
Agent C | Agent C | ZYXA01EF01 | New Business
```

Then trough queries with joins and calculated fields you could build your score table.

```
Agent   | Policy Ref | Transaction Type | Score
Agent A | ABCD01EF01 | New Business     | 0.5 
Agent B | ABCD01EF01 | New Business     | 0.5
Agent C | ZYXA01EF01 | New Business     | 1.0
```

Then you can use a count of agent for each policy ref.

You may have other more simple or elegant ways to do this, but at least I think this should work.